# Android 4.0.4 Soft Keyboard on WebView Results in White Page

Tags: android, webview, keypress

If I load a large html file in a webview running Android 4.0.4 and then press on an input in that webview it works normally. However, when I click a button on the keyboard ("a" or even using voice input) the whole screen goes white and only the input that was initially selected can be seen by the user.

This works perfectly fine in 4.0.3 and 4.1. It only happens in webviews that are longer than the screen (i.e. scrolling required).

Comment: Hiee.. I got the same issue now. can i know how did u solved this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, after variable trying.
The reason is you do your stuff before input.onblur finishes its work.
So one of the solution is just wrapper your stuff with setTimeout()

here is an example

```
var ipt = document.createElement('input');
ipt.type = "text";
document.body.appendChild(ipt);

ipt.onkeyup = function(e){
    e=e||window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
        ipt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(key==13){
        ipt.blur();
        setTimeout(function(){

           //DO YOUR STUFF HERE !!!

        }, 100);
    }
}
```